# how to create a single register page for every user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have patient and doctor as my different roles. 
I want both of them register using a single register page and if we register as a patient then a new patient_id is saved in patient table and patient dashboard is shown.
If We register as doctor then new doctor_id is saved in doctor table and doctor dashboard is opened.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: how would you prevent patients from registering as doctors? You might want to consider having a common users table and separate patient/doctor tables that hold a foreign key constraint on that users table

Comment: Are using devise gem for authentication ??